# Should gem's development dependencies restate required runtime dependencies?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, dependency-management

I can not find any documentation on this. My intuition was that [`add_development_dependency`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/rubygems/rdoc/Gem/Specification.html#method-i-add_development_dependency) from a gemspec file should list only additional dependencies that are needed for development and testing and can rely on dependencies specified with `add_runtime_dependency` to be installed.

I was surprised to discover that [`gem test`](http://github.com/rubygems/rubygems-test/blob/master/README.txt) command installs only development dependencies, and fails if any runtime dependency is needed during tests.

Is it only `gem test` quirk or should development dependencies always restate required runtime dependencies, like below:

```
Gem::Specification.new do |s|
  # ...
  s.add_runtime_dependency 'rack'
  s.add_runtime_dependency 'net-http-persistent'
  s.add_development_dependency 'rack-test'
  s.add_development_dependency 'webmock'
  s.add_development_dependency 'rack'
  s.add_development_dependency 'net-http-persistent'
end
```

?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think `gem test` assumes that you have installed the gem you want to test before you actually try to test it.

```
gem install whatever
gem test whatever
```

All the [tests](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems-test/blob/master/test/test_execute.rb) would indicate that this is the case - they call `install_stub_gem` first, which installs a fake gem to run the `gem test` commands against.

I've never seen a gem duplicate all its runtime dependencies as development dependencies, and the language of the [docs](http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/20#development_dependencies) suggests that it wouldn't make sense to do so:

> #### development dependencies
>
> Gems that are used for development purposes **only**. *(emphasis mine)*

Gems that are also runtime dependencies would therefore not fit into this category.

Comment: Thanks, this indeed makes more sense!